# Why is iTerm2 shifting the text input to top of page, moving cmd hist 'off the screen'

Tags: macos, iterm2

Why is iTerm2 shifting my text input to the middle or top of the page, and also shifting the history up? When it moves my text input to the top, that means I can only see a few lines of history, and everything else is off screen. ie: doing `ls` in a dir with many files, I won't see the command, and will not see the first x lines of output, and will only see the bottom 3-5 lines (all located at the very top of the window).

It seemed to happen after a settings change (re-opening previous windows on app start), unsure if it's related.

MacOS BigSur 11.2.3, iTerm2 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a screen resize problem. It occurs if I disconnect an external monitor or screen mirror when used as another display.

It can be fixed by triggering a screen resize manually - full-screen to small window and back again, 4-finger swiping up and dragging full screen into desktop window, and then back into it's own full-screen window in top window bar, etc.